# Modifying standard case object

Tags: apex, visualforce, case

I have an existing standard Case page. My customer would like to add a custom "Escalate" button to the page so that when a user clicks this button, they will be prompted to select from available product families. When this first selection is made, they will then be provided input fields based on their initial product family selection. When the user fills out these fields and submits the form, the existing Case page will have those fields/values added under an "Escalation Info" section.

The customer envisioned this happening with a single, or series of visualforce pages

I'm asking for some advice in the direction I should go. I don't necessarily want to override a standard case object with a custom visualforce page, but rather use a visualforce page to gather data from the user and then add it to an existing case sObject. Is this something I can do with visualforce, or will this require some more advanced Apex programming?  How should I get started on this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, all you need is a page that uses the `Case` standard controller paired with an extension (I imagine you will need one).

```
<apex:page standardController="case" extensions="myCustomExtension">
    <!-- markup -->
</apex:page>
```

The `standardController` piece is what allows you to use the page as a button.